# How do I convert weight of compressed, liquid $\rm CO_2$ in canister to cubic meters at atmospheric pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, gas

I need compressed $\rm CO_2$ for a project I'm working on, and am trying to figure out how much volume of gaseous $\rm CO_2$ I get from a given weight of liquid $\rm CO_2$ in canister. As far as I can tell the answer lies in the ideal gas law, but I'm unsure how to set up an expression that would give me an answer. Everything is known except for the gaseous volume.

P(liquid) = 800 psi;
v(liquid) = 0.01686229 m^3;
T(liquid) = 20°C

P(gas) = 14.7 psi (atmosphere);
v(gas) = ?
T(gas) = 20°C

So for example 10lb $\rm CO_2$, how would I calculate the gaseous volume?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is see if your product is PSI-G or PSI-A. Wait... is it compressed or liquified?

Comment: @JEB the co2 in the canister is liquified, and I think at around 800 PSI. I'm assuming that's PSIG? adding 14.7 for 814.7 PSIA.

Comment: What would be wrong with using the relation $\frac{P_1V_1}{T_1}=\frac{P_2V_2}{T_2}$ and then solve for $V_2$ (or $V_1$)? You are assuming it to be an ideal gas? Or does it have something to do with the fact that the compressed CO2 is in liquid phase?

Comment: @josephh you can’t use the ideal gas law for liquid.

Comment: You need to know the volume or weight of the liquid  CO2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law), $PV=nRT$, for a first order approximation.* I'll leave it to you to figure out how many moles of CO2, $n$, are in ten pounds.

But note! Just because the liquid in the bottle starts out at 20C, that doesn't mean that the gas will flow out at that same temperature. In fact, if you open the valve wide enough, you'll get a mix of gas and dry ice snow at around -78C. You'll need to supply heat if you want gas at 20C.

---

*I'm not a chemist. I don't know how to what extent CO2 will behave differently from an ideal gas at room temperature and pressure.

Comment: It won’t behave at all like an ideal gas, especially if it is liquified! At extremely high pressures of gas you would need to use something like the virial equation of state to capture non ideal behaviors. For the liquid the problem is quite a bit harder.

Comment: @MattHanson, the question isn't about the liquid. The question asks, "what is the volume of ten pounds of CO2 at 20C and 14.7 psi.